read date/time from a csv file then mark it on chart
the following code read a csv file with simple data date/time then mark it on the chart which bar it is, but somehow I keep getting errors of not being able to read the csv file:
#property strict

// Input parameters
input string csvFilePath = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test.csv"; // File path to CSV

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert initialization function                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit()
{
    // Read and print CSV file content
    if (!PrintCSVFileContent(csvFilePath))
    {
        Print("Failed to read CSV file: ", csvFilePath);
        return INIT_FAILED;
    }

    return INIT_SUCCEEDED;
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Print CSV file content                                           |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
bool PrintCSVFileContent(const string filePath)
{
    int fileHandle = FileOpen(filePath, FILE_CSV | FILE_READ);
    if (fileHandle == INVALID_HANDLE)
    {
        Print("Failed to open CSV file: ", GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    string data[];
    int linesRead = FileReadArray(fileHandle, data);
    FileClose(fileHandle);

    if (linesRead <= 0)
    {
        Print("No data read from CSV file: ", filePath);
        return false;
    }

    Print("CSV file content:");
    for (int i = 0; i < linesRead; i++)
    {
        Print(data[i]);
    }

    return true;
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert tick function                                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()
{
    // Nothing to do on tick
}

The error is : 2024.04.07 13:58:06.358  temp1 EURUSD,H1: Failed to read CSV file: C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.csv
2024.04.07 13:58:06.358 temp1 EURUSD,H1: Failed to open CSV file: 5002
2024.04.07 13:58:06.359 temp1 EURUSD,H1: initialization failed (1)
2024.04.07 13:58:06.359 temp1 EURUSD,H1: uninit reason 8
I supposed it is simple code but not sure why it has problems, really appreciate any help. thanks

Hi Alan, did you check these posts?https://www.mql5.com/en/search#!keyword=Error%205002&module=mql5_module_forum
